# To create an array that contains each digit as separate element from integer in JavaScript

Tags: javascript

My understanding is that bellow code will create an array name digits which contains all digits from n, I'm I right?

var n =  123456789; 
var digits = (""+n).split("");

**But I did'n understood (""+n) ?**
Can anyone help me?
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

`(""+n)` means type casting the variable `n` into string

```
var n = 32;  // n is integer type
n = "" + n; // now n is string type (n = "32")
var digits = n.split("");//execute string split function
//now digits = ['3','2'] (array of chars or single string charector)
```

Answer (score 1):

n is type of a number, with `(""+n)`, you are basically converting n to a string, so you can use split method. numbers do not have a split method

Answer (score 1):

It is doing the job of implicit type casting from int to string.
For ex.

```
4 + 2
```

returns 6

```
4 + 2 + "2"
```

returns 62

```
"2" + 2 + 4
```

returns 224

The integers following "" are implicitly converted to string and cancatenated.

Answer (score 1):

`var n = 123456789;` create a variable `n` of numeric type. When you use `+""` with a variable of numeric type javascript autamatically treat it as string and the operation return a string. So  `(""+n)` will cast the `n` variable to string type.

Answer (score 1):

When concat a number with string, js cast it to string. In your code, `n` is number, but when concat with a empty string(`""`), casting to string. In other way you can call `toString()` function. You can run follow snippet to try it

```js
var n = 123456789; 

console.log(typeof n); //number
console.log(typeof (""+n)); //string
console.log((""+n).split(""));
console.log(n.toString().split(""));
```

Comment: Thank you Mohammad for the detail explanation.